# Display event on click of Date with drupal fullcalendar module

Tags: datetime, javascript

i have made a event calendar with fullcalendar module.

[image]

Now what i need is that when a user clicks on the date box for example 9-sept he should be send to a custom url with the full date in the URL.

And i need to highlight the date boxes with colors based on my event type.

Any clues ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done this with the Drupal Full Calendar **Views** module?

If yes, then its quite simple...

1. Add another field for "event date" and format the date in the format
   you wish to use in the url , e.g., Y-M-D , then hide that field
   using "exclude from display".
2. In the field you want to have as the
   link, click re-write results.
3. Enter the path you wish to link to,
   using the event date pattern rewrite pattern you created in step 1.
   Your url should look like `<a href="/events/[event-date]">Link</a>`

As for highlighting the colour depending on event type, create another field for "node:type", and use that in the same rewrite results field as above, so your rewrite field is...

```
<a class="[node-type]" href="/events/[event-date]">Link</a>
```

Which will render out as...

```
<a class="event" href="/events/2014-06-24">Link</a>
```

Then in CSS, declare classes for your node type, for example...

```
.event {background:red}
```